# Visual studio web, what file do i upload to server?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio, web

I'm a little confused, since a day or 2 i've been programming with visual studio 2013 web express. i've made a C# web form (.aspx). i used to program normal html/css in Adobe Dreamweaver.
But unlike a normal .HTML document i cannot find a file to just click and open in my browser. and so i do not know how to upload my project to my hosting server. when i debug it, it shows up in my browser and it tells me it is the file with .aspx extension but when i try to manually open this file it just tells me there's something wrong with my page (incorrect code etc.)
Anyone can tell me how i do this? could not find a solution in google so i thought i'd give stackoverflow a chance :)

Thanks!
Gr.

Comment: An asp.net project works a little bit differently than an html/css webpage.  In asp.net the c# code you are writing gets executing on the server side, unlike html which is read client side.  So when you are just trying to click a file to open your webpage, it is no working because you do not have a server to run the code for your webpage.  When you debug the project in visual studio, the project runs because it is being hosted on a local IIS server on your machine.

Comment: Search for "deploy"; see [the results for "deploy asp.net visual studio 2013"](https://www.google.com/search?q=deploy+asp.net+visual+studio+2013).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, a website programmed with ASP.Net requires Internet Information Services (IIS) to run.

Visual Studio has its own built-in mini version of IIS for development, but to deploy to production you'll need a Windows Server with IIS. You should check that your hosting provider supports IIS before you do anything else.

Assuming you have IIS running, and you've configured a website in IIS with an empty directory, ready to host your project there are a couple of different options you have for deployment:

1. Just copy everything in the website to the server (all files & folders). This is simplest, and allows you to tweak things on the fly, but is the least secure.
2. Use Visual Studio's packaging and deployment utility. Not much to say here, other than read the manual.

Answer (score 0):

The .aspx pages, .ascx controls, the bin folder with your .dll files, web.config, App_Themes, App_LocalResources, etc. And then you'll need to set up a new web site on IIS.